# How to perform arithmetic operations on dataframe in spark using select and map?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to manipulate dataframe using select in spark scala. I want to multiply column values by 10 using select but it fails. Also let me know how to perform map, flatmap, reducebykey operations on dataframe using select.

```
df1.select("Sales"*10,"Profit"*10).show()

df1.select("Sales").map(x=>x*10).show()
```

Help me to solve this issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use col instead of string :

```
df1
.select
 (
  (col("Sales")*10).as("Sales"),
  (col("Profit")*10).as("Profit")
)
.show()
```